# Date_trunc by month? Postgresql

Tags: sql, date

How would I get the date_trunc by month?
Would it be like this?

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', l_date) month
    FROM this_table
    GROUP BY month
```

l_date is the column where I would pull the date from.

Comment: postgresql or eclipse

Comment: date_part('month', l_date)

Comment: Yes, that is how you use `date_trunc`. It will return the date truncated to month precision, e.g. `2014-05-09 16:03:51` will be returned as `2014-05-01 00:00:00`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that should work just fine in `Postgres`.
Have you tested it?

If your date is `2014-03-16 10:00:00am`:

`date_trunc('month', l_date)` would give you `2014-03-01 00:00:00` (sets it to first day of truncated month)

`date_part('month', l_date)` would give you `03` which it looks like that is what you are looking for

Comment: Is there a way to get each month separately?

Comment: Also, is there a way to make so it doesn't give you a row for every month?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for with that

Comment: When I do that it goes...
        Loc  month1 month2 month3
        Loc1 1      
        Loc1        2
        Loc1               3
        Loc2 1
        Loc2        2
        Loc2               3 etc...

Is there a way to get it so it has one row per location, and one column per month? Sorry if that is confusing, that should have came out like a table.